# можно ли каким-то образом создать массив с переменными внутри него

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть первый массив со значениями внутри него, чтобы обращаться к каждому из них мне нужно создавать новую переменную и указывать в ней номер контента массива = [0],[1],[2]
Для того, чтобы не записывайть новую переменную каждый раз, я хотел бы создать один массив с этими переменными и уже получить доступ через этот массив, просто добавив к нему номер переменной

```
const text = ["На концерты", "На мероприятия","На фестиваль", "На шоу", "На онлайн-событие"];

let firstText = text[0]
let twoText = text[1]
let threeText = text[2]
let fourText = text[3]
let fiveText = text[4]
```

Comment: Переведите на русский ваш вопрос

Comment: не майтесь ерундой. Для чего вам эти переменные, если можно просто использовать text[0], text[1] и т.д.

Comment: ^ или сделайте ассоциативный массив, если не хотите помнить номерочки, а работать с именами

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = {
    firstText: "На концерты",
    twoText: "На мероприятия",
    threeText: "На фестиваль",
    fourText: "На шоу",
    fiveText: "На онлайн-событие"
};

text["firstText"] /* или */ text.firstText
text["twoText"] /* или */ text.twoText
// и так далее
```

Answer (score 0):

То, что Вы пытались сделать - это [деструктурирующее присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const text = ["На концерты", "На мероприятия", "На фестиваль", "На шоу", "На онлайн-событие"];

let [firstText, twoText, threeText, fourText, fiveText] = text;

console.log(firstText, twoText, threeText, fourText, fiveText);
```