# Можно ли каким то образом при вызове функции в другом блоке изменить значение её переменной?

Tags: javascript, html

Можно ли каким то образом при вызове функции в другом блоке изменить значение её переменной?
у меня есть вот такая функция

```
function typeText() {
    let line = 0; // номер строки
    let count = 0; // счетчик позиции
    let out = ''; // то что мы делаем
    function typeLine() {
        // рисует строки
        let timeout = setInterval(function () {
            out += text.firstText[line][count];
            typewriter.innerHTML = out;
            count++;
            if (count >= text.firstText[line].length) {
                count = 0;
                    line++;
                    } if (line == text.firstText.length) {
                        clearTimeout(timeout)
                        return true;
                    }
        }, 100);
    }
    typeLine();
}
typeText();
```

я хочу вызвать её внутри другой функции, но изменив ей first text внутри **out += text.firstText[line][count];**

я конечно могу создать еще раз похожую функцию но уже с другим out, но это займет очень много кода. т.к мне нужно изменить не в одном месте

Comment: У вас вопрос в контексте ответа на этот вопрос? [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460045/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460045/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be)

Answer (score 0):

Сделать в функцию параметр и использовать его, если нужно

```
function typeText(outText) {
    ...
    ...
    if (outText)
        out += outText
```

где-то в другой функции соответственно

```
typeText('какой-то текст');
```